# How to make a Federate object to appear inside another Federate software?

Tags: simulation, high-level-architecture, dis

I am using Pitch pRTI Free and a Map federate and my objective is to make a "random vehicle" to appear inside this Map federate. I have already created a object instance with Spatial, EntityType, EntityIdentifier, ForceIdentifier, Marking, IsConcealed and DamageState. All them from netn2_2010.xml FOM.

The object was published, subscribed, registered and the Map federate shows in "Known Instances" my "MyFederate" object, but it still does not appear inside the Map software. Anyone knows what can this be?
What do I need to make the Map software create this "random vehicle"? Is there any method from rtiAmbassador or anything else?

I have already tried a free license of coreDS X-Plane HLA plugin and the X-Plane object appeared inside the Map Software, so it is probably not any pRTI configuration or a problem with the Map federate.

Comment: Please provide a [reprex], and clarify exactly what your problem is. :)

Comment: Could you provide some more information about the "Map" federate?

Comment: I managed to make it today. The Map federate is a simulator from Masa Group.  I was missing to set the "Marking" attribute. As I said I have created a object instance with Spatial, EntityType, EntityIdentifier, ForceIdentifier, Marking, IsConcealed and DamageState attributes, but I forgot to set Marking.